# Excecute "taskkill /f /im chrome.exe" even when no chrome process is running

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, cmd

I execute this command

```
taskkill /f /im chrome.exe
```

In order to stop all chrome process and it works fine only when there is a chrome process running. Most of time I need to run the command even when there is no process of chrome running. How is it possible using command line?

*PS:* When I run the command and no chrome process is running I got an error like 
*chrome.exe not found*

Comment: If it gives you the error output, it sounds like it's running just fine

Answer (score 5):

Actually the command does execute, as you would not get an error message otherwise.

Anyway, I suppose you basically want to suppress the error message, which can be accomplished by appending [`2> nul`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to the command line (separated by a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>):

```cmd
taskkill /f /im chrome.exe 2> nul
```

If you want to reset the exit code (`ErrorLevel`), write [`ver`](http://ss64.com/nt/ver.html)[`> nul`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) into the next line (this works because `ver` is a command that never fails and resets the `ErrorLevel` value):

```cmd
taskkill /f /im chrome.exe
ver > nul
```

Or in a single line:

```cmd
taskkill /f /im chrome.exe & ver > nul
```

Of course you may combine these two measures:

```cmd
taskkill /f /im chrome.exe 2> nul & ver > nul
```

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell, you can simply do one of the following:

`Get-Process Chrome -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -Force`

or

`Stop-Process Chrome -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`